# Error while deleting record on update using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, lightining

[image]

when i am updating a checkbox using record page a trigger is running on update which is deleting the recently updated records. The trigger is running fine but after deleting a record its showing me above error how can i fix that

Comment: Please use Debug Logs to debug what exact error you are getting.

Comment: the apex code is running without error. 
I guess  its because the current record page cannot access the current record as its deleted by the trigger

Answer (score 0):

- Trigger

```
Trigger AccountTrigger on Account (Before Delete){
    if(Trigger.isDelete){  
 AccountClassDemo1.beforeMethod(Trigger.Old)
    }
}
```

- Apex

AccountClassDemo1

```
public class AccountClassDemo1{
    public static void beforeMethod(List<Account> newList){
        for(Account acc: newList){
            if(acc.Active==true){
                acc.adderror('Not Deleted');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what will be better when applying your solution?